# How do I Pre-load Simple Products Tier Pricing of Configurable Product using JSON?

Tags: tierprice, configurable-product, product-view

Currently, I am using the following code in view.phtml to retrieve tier price data:

```
var Tier_Prices = <?php echo json_encode($_product->getTierPrice()) ?>;
```

This only works for simple products and not configurable products that contain simple products. The output on the configurable products shows as:

```
var Tier_Prices = [];
```

My question is how do I retrieve or preload tier price data from a configurable product that contains multiple simple products?